Trouble deploying express to azure app service local git, failing while linking dependencies
Attempting to deploy express.js application to azure app service with local git. The app runs fine on my local but fails while linking dependencies. It is running on port 80. I am deploying without node_modules. There is build of react inside the public folder.
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752150035Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752154235Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752157335Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752160335Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752163435Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752166335Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752169535Z 
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752172235Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752175535Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752178335Z NodeJS Version : v18.19.1
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752181035Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-06-08T19:51:30.752184035Z 
2024-06-08T19:51:31.193914248Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-06-08T19:51:31.244489951Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2024-06-08T19:51:31.276188603Z Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2024-06-08T19:51:31.280345636Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2024-06-08T19:51:31.280378236Z Build Operation ID: 41e9c42e-d2f1-434c-a412-46c9c404420a
2024-06-08T19:51:31.485113164Z Environment Variables for Application Insight's IPA Codeless Configuration exists..
2024-06-08T19:51:31.507160140Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544600937Z Running #!/bin/sh
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544629338Z 
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544633938Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544637538Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544640938Z 
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544644138Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544647438Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544650738Z      export PORT=8080
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544654538Z fi
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544657638Z 
2024-06-08T19:51:31.544660738Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" cd prodoslo1 && yarn install && yarn run prod
2024-06-08T19:51:31.955441605Z yarn install v1.22.15
2024-06-08T19:51:32.085875742Z [1/5] Validating package.json...
2024-06-08T19:51:32.089607272Z [2/5] Resolving packages...
2024-06-08T19:51:32.662441527Z [3/5] Fetching packages...
2024-06-08T19:51:52.373047412Z info fsevents@2.3.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
2024-06-08T19:51:52.373369015Z info "fsevents@2.3.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2024-06-08T19:51:52.395040552Z [4/5] Linking dependencies...
2024-06-08T19:51:53.245750111Z error Could not write file "/home/site/wwwroot/prodoslo1/yarn-error.log": "EROFS: read-only file system, open '/home/site/wwwroot/prodoslo1/yarn-error.log'"
2024-06-08T19:51:53.246134615Z error An unexpected error occurred: "EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/home/site/wwwroot/prodoslo1/node_modules'".
2024-06-08T19:51:53.246313917Z info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.


package.json

"dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "@sentry/node": "^7.58.1",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node-babel-7": "^2.0.7",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "debug": "^4.3.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "google-auth-library": "^8.9.0",
    "google-spreadsheet": "^4.0.2",
    "googleapis": "^120.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mathjs": "^11.11.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "query-string": "^8.1.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2",
    "swagger-autogen": "^2.23.7",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.6.10",
    "twilio": "^4.19.3",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "ws": "^8.15.1",
    "xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.1/xlsx-0.19.1.tgz"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js}": [
      "yarn run format",
      "git add ."
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.22.5",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }

Not sure what to do about it. I would expect an error to tell me whats wrong.

If possible, Share your GitHub repository?

fsevents is a native macOS library, meaning file system events. It's typically used by file watchers, or any code monitoring file system changes or other activity. Azure App Service for Linux runs on Ubuntu, so the library can't be used.
It appears to be an indirect dependency, possibly stemming from the reference to nodemon.
You can check where the dependency is coming from, inside the project directory, using either:
npm ls fsevents

...or...
yarn why fsevents

You'll then need to make suitable adjustments such that this library is not used.
Edit:
You probably also need to grant permissions for Node to be able to write to the log.
Steps to Set Permissions

Access Kudu Console:

Go to the Azure Portal.
Navigate to your App Service instance.
Click on "Advanced Tools" in the left-hand menu and then click "Go".


Open the Console:

In the Kudu console, go to the "Debug console" tab and select "Bash".


Set Permissions:

Use the chmod command to set the necessary permissions for the directory. For example, to give read, write, and execute permissions to the owner, you can run:
chmod 755 /home/site/wwwroot/prodoslo1





If you're still getting an EROFS: read-only file system error, it typically means that the file system is mounted as read-only, and you will not be able to change permissions. In such a case, check your app service configuration to ensure that the file system is mounted with read-write permissions.
